# How can i build docker wildfly image on windows

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly

I try to build docker image on windows, my docker file looks like:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:13.0.0.Final 
COPY target/dashboard.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/dashboard.war
```

but build failure with error message:

`image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform`

Its possible to build and run wildfly image on windows machine?

Comment: Possibly you are using windows containers. Try switching to linux.. Right click on docker icon, switch to linux containers.

Comment: Is a way to usage wildfly image without switch to linux container?

Comment: No it is not possible to use `jboss/wildfly:13.0.0.Final` when using windows containers. I guess though that you can build your own windows wildfly image. I can't help you more on that since I have no experience on windows containers.